# Show HTML <select> element to a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I’ve been trying to display a  element to `div#log`. I'm using jquery `append()` method to insert options at the end of the selected elements.

However, the results of the `drop-down list` are not what I expected.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Display DOM to a specific id (div#log)
  $("#log").html("<select class='form-control selcls' id='meterOption'>");
  var meterNum = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    $("#log").append("<option value=" + meterNum + ">" + meterNum + "</option>");
    meterNum++;
  }
  $("#log").append("</select>");

});
```

```css
.selcls {
  padding: 9px;
  border: solid 1px #517B97;
  outline: 0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #CAD9E3), to(#FFFFFF));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #CAD9E3 1px, #FFFFFF 25px);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

A part of the code is shown below.

```
  $("#log").html("<select class='form-control selcls' id='meterOption'>");
  var meterNum = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    $("#log").append("<option value=" + meterNum + ">" + meterNum + "</option>");
    meterNum++;
  }
  $("#log").append("</select>");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Display DOM to a specific id (div#log)
  $("#log").html("<select class='form-control selcls' id='meterOption'></select>");
  var meterNum = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    $("#log > select").append("<option value=" + meterNum + ">" + meterNum + "</option>");
    meterNum++;
  }
  // $("#log").append("</select>");

});
```

```css
.selcls {
  padding: 9px;
  border: solid 1px #517B97;
  outline: 0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 25, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #CAD9E3), to(#FFFFFF));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #CAD9E3 1px, #FFFFFF 25px);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log">


</div>
```

Not `$("#log")`, `$("#log > select")`.

If you wanna append at `select`, you have to find `select` Tag.

But, you found `$("#log")`, it is not `select` Tag.

So, you should write `${"#log > select")`

Answer (score 4):

1. You should append the option in the select and append the select into the div.
2. Currently you are appending the option into the div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Display DOM to a specific id (div#log)
  $("#log").html("<select class='form-control selcls' id='meterOption'>");
  var meterNum = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    $("#meterOption").append("<option value=" + meterNum + ">" + meterNum + "</option>");
    meterNum++;
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
$("#log").html("<select class='form-control selcls' id='meterOption'>");
#log becomes <select...>
#log.append("x1")
#log becomes <select...>x1
#log.append("x2")
#log becomes <select...>x1x2
#log.append("</select>")
#log becomes <select...>x1x2</select>
```

What you got was JQuery being "helpful" and closing your initial select for you.  Not a bad thing, if you know it's happening.

```
$("#log").html("<select class='form-control selcls' id='meterOption'>");
#log becomes <select...></select>
#log.append("x1")
#log becomes <select...></select>x1
#log.append("x2")
#log becomes <select...></select>x1x2
#log.append("</select>")
#log stays <select...></select>x1x2
```

You're adding the options to the div, not to the select.

```
$("#meterOption").append("<option value=" + meterNum + ">" + meterNum + "</option>");
```

will add the items to the select box.

The closing /select does not need to be added.